# Cloning custom home page

Tags: wordpress, clone

I want to know how to clone custom home page in wordpress. Why I want to do this? I want to do home page with 2 languages, but I cant transate this custom page and I want to home page as regular wordpress page, then I can translate this.

I already tried this by using Page Builder, but prebuilt (clone:pages) is empty, and I dont know how I get there this custom home page.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create page template for home page.
and then admin side create a new page named home and select home page template in template section.
now your page is act as other normal pages.

Comment: How can I crate page template for home page ?

Comment: go through twentyfourteen->page-templates
and then copy one of template from there.
past it in your template directory.
replace twentyfourteen with your them name.
and then place your index page's code between he get_header(); and get_footer();

Comment: and don't forgot  to change the template name .. in first line
 * Template Name: Home Page
and also change the name of php file similar EX. home_page.php

Comment: i think now you got it.
and if you found this stuff useful then please click up whats and correct this ans ..
thansk

Comment: uuh, If I do this way, this page looks veery ugly.

Comment: I dont know why its not working for me, but if I do this, then I got only menus in to my page

Comment: this is the best method. every time i am using this and got proper result.

Comment: Yea, I get this theme template, but I need this homepage, where is gallery etc ..

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates refer this link for more info..

it may be useful stuff